# Is there an easy way to get the creator object of an object in objective-c / iPhone-OS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Example:

I have an class that inherits from UIImageView. An object creates an instance from that class. Now, that class needs a weak reference to it's parent. I could make an initializer where the object has to pass "self" to the new created object. But I feel that there is a better way. Is there any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at:

- [**SO question: How to message superview**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537853/how-to-message-superview-in-objective-c)
- [**SO question: Proper design for delegates and controllers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820808/objective-c-cocoa-proper-design-for-delegates-and-controllers/820995#820995)

Basically, these questions make the same conclusions as are made here: there is no built in way. You'll need to reference yourself, like

```
-(id)initWithParent:(id)parent
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not. If you need this you'll have to set the parent during or right after initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to do this natively in the language.

The problem you would have with such a function even if it was available is what would occur if the "parent" object has been deallocated?